# NS suffixed members in DOM Core

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

The DOM Core standard is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core

This standard defines the fundamental interfaces which are implemented in the DOM of web browsers. Those interfaces among others contain NS suffixed members.

***Interface Document***

- createElementNS
- createAttributeNS
- getElementsByTagNameNS

***Interface Element***

- getAttributeNS
- setAttributeNS
- removeAttributeNS
- getAttributeNodeNS
- setAttributeNodeNS
- getElementsByTagNameNS
- hasAttributeNS
- setIdAttributeNS

***Interface NamedNodeMap***

- getNamedItemNS
- removeNamedItemNS

I haven't looked into this much, but it seems to me that those members exist purely for XML documents. Is that correct? Does that mean that web-developers who create HTML web-pages can ignore those members?

Comment: Yes to both questions, though rather than "can ignore them" it might be better to say "will not be used in documents that don't use namespaces".

Comment: @RobG Do namespaces apply to HTML documents or is it purely "a XML thing"?

Comment: Just XML. Namespaces allow multiple DTDs or schemas to be used in the one document (though they can be used with just one DTD/XSD). HTML does not allow multiple schemas, the DOCTYPE indicates the DTD/XSD to use (up to 4.01 and various XHTML versions). HTML5 does away with that, using a [DOCTYPE](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-doctype) of case insensitive HTML (i.e. <!DOCTYPE html>).

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, there are some [predefined namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#namespaces) for [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/), [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/),...

So the different functions you cited in your question such as createElementNS, createAttributeNS are useful, by example, for manipulating SVG inside HTML5.